# iOS passing data between two Views

Tags: ios

I'm using two views (view controllers VC1 and VC2) and passing data from VC1 to VC2 
I stored the values for two variables in VC2

```
  //VC1 store obj to VC2
self.VC2.twtid=ide;
self.VC2.urlString=[[NSURL alloc]  initWithString:vurl];
```

I received the values after VC2 was shown.
My problem is when I click in any cell in VC1 for the second time.
When I navigate back to VC1(tableview) again and tried to select cell, the values aren't stored again.

```
  //VC.h I declare the two var 
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *twtid;

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURL *urlString;
```

note: I didn't use prepareForSegue.without Segue!!

Comment: Show your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code

Comment: do alloc init befor assign data

Answer (score 1):

Use global variables othereise use Segue methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController2 *VC2 = (ViewController2 *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
VC2.url = urlString; // use your variable over here, this is just and example
[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:^{         }];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```

**user presentViewController or pushViewController** as per your requirement

Comment: @MohammedAlhadhel  than please upvote my answer and tick as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the VC2 as VC1's property, just init it every time.